# Issues with a recursive factorial: Segmentation fault

Tags: recursion, assembly, segmentation-fault, arm, subroutine

```
.global main
.type main%function

main:
        ldr r1,[r1,#4]    // take the argv[1]
        ldrb r1,[r1]    // take the value
        sub r1,r1,#48    // convert from char to dec
        mov r2,r1
        push {ip,lr}
        bl fact
        pop {ip,lr}
        ldr r0,=message
        b printf
fact:
        sub r2,r2,#1    // decrease the num
        push {r2,lr}    // save the num and lr
        cmp r2,#1    // compare the num with 1
        blne fact    // if the num is NOT 1, then BL the fact subroutine recursively
        pop {r2,lr}   // if the num is 1, then start to restore the nums in the stack
        mul r1,r1,r2    // and multiply them
        bx lr    // then returns
message:
        .asciz "Factorial: %d"
```

If I execute it, I get this Segmentation Fault:

```
$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault
```

What could be the reason? I tried to remove the printf call to see if there were problems with printf, but still get the error, so there must be a problem inside fact subroutine.

Comment: main reads argv[1][0] without checking argc, and you didn’t provide a parameter, so argv[1] is null.

Comment: @prl lol how can I be so dumb? Do you suggest me to delete the post? It does not deserve to be on stackoverflow

Comment: @Mnkisd Even better: write an answer to your question and post it here, so others with the same question can progit from the wisdom you received!

Answer (score 2):

Lol. I fixed the issue.

I just didn't pass any argument by commandline, so basically argv[1] is null, thus Segmentation fault.

I just need to execute with:

```
./a.out 7
```

for example 7 to do the factorial of 7.